# How to make sure execution of a network call has been completed when we get onSuccess for another call in android using RX Java

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2, rx-android

I have two network calls both are called inside a method `xyz`.

The network calls are as shown below:

```
SingleObserver<RegisterResponse> observer = new SingleObserver<RegisterResponse>() {
     @Override
     public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onSuccess(@NonNull RegisterResponse registerResponse) {
        }
     }

     @Override
     public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
      }
     }
    };
```

This is my another network call:

```
TrueTimeRx.build().initializeRx("time.apple.com")
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.subscribe(date -> {
 Timber.d("TrueTime was initialized at: %s" + date);
 actualDate = TrueTime.now();
 }, throwable -> {
 });
```

I want to make sure actual date is set before I get into onSuccess of first network call. Some times executing of second network call fails as the first one gets executed very fast.

Can anyone please let me know how can I make sure actual date is set everyting before onSuccess gets called.

Answer (score 0):

As you need the result of first network call then u can use Observable rather than SingleObserver. In observable there is another call back which is onNext. So you can initialize your second network all in this onNext() block. Then it will be always ensured that you have the result before calling second network call.

Comment: Can you please share code snippet on how that can be done?

Comment: https://blog.doordash.com/synchronizing-network-calls-with-rxjava-d30f7db66fb9 please read this. you will get the clue